# What is behaviour of sql component serve as producer in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am reading camel-example-sql, it has two routes defined as below:

```
<!-- route that generate new orders and insert them in the database -->
<route id="generateOrder-route">
  <from uri="timer:foo?period=5s"/>
  <transform>
    <method ref="orderBean" method="generateOrder"/>
  </transform>
  <to uri="sql:{{sql.insertOrder}}"/>
  <log message="Inserted new order ${body[id]}"/>
</route>

<!-- route that process the orders by picking up new rows from the database
     and when done processing then update the row to mark it as processed -->
<route id="processOrder-route">
  <from uri="sql:{{sql.selectOrder}}?consumer.onConsume={{sql.markOrder}}"/>
  <to uri="bean:orderBean?method=processOrder"/>
  <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```

I can understand first route, which fires every 5 second. But when does second route be triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd route uses the SQL select statement from `{{sql.selectOrder}}` to query the database, and if there is a resultset, thean each row becomes a message that is routed. If the resultset is empty then no message is routed.

The 2nd route use a scheduler that runs every every 500 millis (eg the consumer.delay) option.

- http://camel.apache.org/sql-component

Comment: I figured out that there are a lot other components support this kind of "polling" feature also have .delay properties available.